# How to limit concurrent connections to Go API

Tags: go

i am starting up a Go API with listenandserve to accept HTTP requests.

How can I achieve the below goal?

1. Allow maximum 100 simultaneous HTTP requests
2. The 101st request (and any others) should wait for 10mins to attempt to fall into this '100 simultaneous' limit (ie hopefully some of the first 100 requests should finish)
3. If 10mins pass and no available request 'slots' have opened up then return error for that request that has been waiting
4. Order of which request 101...102...x that gets run next is unimportant

current version is completely un-go:

```
    timeout := time.After(10 * time.Minute)
    tick := time.Tick(15 * time.Second)
    fullcmdfirst := fmt.Sprintf("netstat -anp | grep procname | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -v grep | wc -l")
    outputfirst, err1first := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", fullcmdfirst).CombinedOutput()
    if strconv.ParseFloat(string(outputfirst)) < 100 {
        return nil
    }

    // Keep trying until we're timed out or lock acquired
    for {
        select {
        // Got a timeout! fail with a timeout error
        case <-timeout:
            return errors.New("Error: timed out ")
        // Got a tick, we should check if we can acquire
        case <-tick:
            fullcmd := fmt.Sprintf("netstat -anp | grep procname | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -v grep | wc -l")
            output, err1 := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", fullcmd).CombinedOutput()
            if strconv.ParseFloat(string(outputfirst)) < 100 {
                l.Printf("start req")
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: i did some reading on mutex/channels but could not find something like this. My current workaround is os.exec to netstat and counting the established connections

Comment: There's a couple distinct and separate questions here. To your first one: you can use a semaphore (in Go, usually just a blocking/buffered channel). The other questions are a bit more involved and there's a lot of different solutions to reason about. What have you tried so far?

Comment: As a starting point: https://gobyexample.com/rate-limiting

Comment: you can wrap previous into a middleware, and that's it.

Comment: middleware? baby steps pls

Comment: I don't understand the 10 minutes waiting. Why not start, when one process is finished?

Comment: Aside from that, you have no control from the server side when a client chooses to timeout. @tooptoop4 Stackoverflow is a site where you ask *peers* for help in programming questions. If you want to have your problem at hand implemented for you, hire a freelancer.

Comment: @apxp you can start when one process finishes, BUT if all 100 processes take more than 10mins then 101st should timeout

Comment: Note that [net.Listener](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listener) is an interface, so you can easily wrap the native listener to count your connections. No need for exec'ing netstat.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg what i'm saying is the server can give a timeout error response if it knows the request has been waiting in line for >=10min

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang: How to timeout a semaphore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647344/golang-how-to-timeout-a-semaphore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the netstats or the tickers or any of that (it won't work anyway - as soon as netstat sees <100 connections nothing is stopping the next 100 request from all noticing and you ending up running 199 requests at once; plus, a request that's waiting to be handled is still going to turn up in netstat - throttling *connections* is a different problem altogether). Just use a buffered channel as a semaphore; it's already thread-safe.

```
sem := make(chan struct{}, 100)

func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    timeout := time.After(10 * time.Minute)
    select {
        case <- timeout:
            http.Error(w, "Sorry", http.StatusUnavailable)
            return
        case sem <- struct{}:
            w.Write([]byte("Hello"))
            <- sem
            return
    }
}
```

Note though that most clients will have already timed out long before the 10 minute mark.

Comment: " throttling connections is a different problem altogether" what does this mean? i thought this will throttle to a limit of 100 connections at once and make others wait for up to 10mins

Comment: Why are there 2 empty returns?

Comment: @apxp just for the sake of being explicit in the example. Presumably a handler will do more than just what is shown, and failing to return after a response could cause undesired behavior.

Comment: @tooptoop4 that would require throttling at the listener, which is more complicated; and clients typically have a much shorter timeout for connections than for a response. For example, browsers will often time out after about 30 seconds if they can't establish a connection, but will wait up to 5 minutes after a connection is established to receive a response. The shown example could have a large number of connections, but will only process the requests up to 100 at a time. The other connections will be established but awaiting a response.